# ExternalEvaluate[pySys, pyCmd] evaluates to Failure[...]

Tags: windows, external-calls, python

`ExternalEvaluate[pySys, pyCmd]` evaluates to `Failure[...]` every time `pyCmd` contains some import statement (otherwise it just works).

The result says it is a Python-related error:

`TypeError required field "type_ignores" missing from Module`

The "problematic" files seem to be:

`C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Links\WolframClientForPython\wolframclient\language\decorators.py`

`C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Links\WolframClientForPython\wolframclient\utils\externalevaluate.py`

Both Mathematica 12.0.0 and Python 3.8.1 are fresh installations.

---

**EDIT**
It is indeed a [problem with Python 3.8](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11590).

Also, in:

`C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Links\WolframClientForPython\setup.py`

it is clearly visible that 3.8 is not """officially""" supported yet.

However, see the accepted answer for a clever workaround.

---

**TL;DR The problem is not present as long as you stick to Python <= 3.7.x, but [Michael Himbeault](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69271/michael-himbeault) did an [awesome job](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212910/67460) making 3.8.x work as well.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading this, turns out the patch is a one-line fix to enable Python 3.8 support. I haven't tested it extensively, but I've included it in my [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Riebart/7622c17237a6ddb2516fd09ea67307ff) that also lets you use Python runtimes installed from the Microsoft Store.

Patch reproduced here directly (applied to 12.0.0) for `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Links\WolframClientForPython\wolframclient\utils\externalevaluate.py`:

```
66c66
<         exec(compile(ast.Module(expressions, []), '', 'exec'), current)
---
>         exec(compile(ast.Module(expressions), '', 'exec'), current)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! 
As soon as I get to my laptop I'll try your fix ;) if it works on my machine (of course it should, but for the sake of full transparency I'll wait until I actually try) I'll accept your answer!

Comment: For the same situation of Mathematica 12.0.0 and Python 3.8.1 in MacOS, this solution simply solved the problem. Great.